# I want to push already created docker images to aws ecr

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, terraform, amazon-ecr

I have already created docker images, I want to push all the external docker images to aws ECR using script or CI/CD pipeline.

In one shot,I know `AWS CodeBuild` process.
But is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Yes there are tons of ways to do this. What specifically do you want to do exactly, what have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of ways for CI/CD.
For example, you can use GitHub Actions

In the free account you have:

```
2,500 free credits/week
Run 1 job at a time
Build on Linux, Windows, and Arm
```

So, you can create a private repository and push all files with Dockerfile.

After that create [Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/quickstart) and configure a job that will build your Docker image and then push it to the ECR

There is [Amazon ECR "Login" Action for GitHub Actions](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/amazon-ecr-login-action-for-github-actions)

```
    - name: Login to Amazon ECR
      id: login-ecr
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

    - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
      env:
        ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        ECR_REPOSITORY: my-ecr-repo
        IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
      run: |
        docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
        docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
```

And it can work as:

- You push changes to the repository
- Actions start, build a docker image and then push docker image to the AWS ECR.

Answer (score 1):

## `docker push`

> I have already created docker images

As you said, images created locally. So, you have these images in your filesystem.

For that case, you may want [`docker push`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/).

E.g.

```
docker image push registry-host:<port>/myimagetag:latest
```

For `ECS` it would be

```
docker push aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/myimagetag:tag
```

## `migrator`

There is a project [docker-archive/migrator: Tool to migrate Docker images from Docker Hub or v1 registry to a v2 registry](https://github.com/docker-archive/migrator). Unfortunately the repository has been archived. But should work.

```
docker run -it \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<key> \
    -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<secret> \
    -e V1_REGISTRY=v1.registry.fqdn \
    -e V2_REGISTRY=v2.registry.fqdn \
docker/migrator
```